# Tibco Spotfire, Remove text from cells

Tags: text, colors, cells, spotfire

I am using Tibco Spotfire to display a list of checked reports.
I have a column "Validation statuts" with (oui , non ) values

I want color cells :
      If statut is valid I  Red color 
      If statut is invalid  Orange color

And remove Text

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different options here such as using a graphical table with icons or a cross table but if I undesrtand correctly, if you only want to use a data table like this:

[image]

then you can create a calculated column as:

```
case [status] 
when "oui" then " " 
when "non" then ""
end as [color status]
```

and set the color for it

[image]